# How to Unmarshal the json array?

Tags: arrays, json, go, slice

There is something wrong when I unmarshal the json array.
How do I correct it ?  the code is:http://play.golang.org/p/AtU9q8Hlye

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Server struct {
    ServerName string
    ServerIP   string
}

type Serverslice struct {
    Name    string
    Servers []Server
}

func main() {
    var s []Serverslice
    str := `{"name":"dxh","servers":[{"serverName":"VPN0","serverIP":"127.0.0.1"},{"serverName":"Beijing_VPN","serverIP":"127.0.0.2"}],
        "name":"dxh1,"servers":[{"serverName":"VPN1","serverIP":"127.0.0.1"},{"serverName":"Beijing_VPN","serverIP":"127.0.0.2"}]}`

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &s) //the wrong line.....................
    fmt.Println(len(s))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're ignoring the error return value from `json.Unmarshal`.  You probably want something like:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &s); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

With that change, we can see that your JSON data isn't valid: `invalid character 's' after object key:value pair`.  There is a missing quote at the end of `"dxh1` on the second line.

Fixing that error and rerunning the program you'll get a different error: `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.Serverslice`.  There are two possible problems here:

1. You meant to decode into an object.  In this case, just declare `s` as a `Serverslice`.  Here is a version of your program that makes that change: http://play.golang.org/p/zgyr_vnn-_
2. Your JSON is supposed to be an array (possible, since it seems to have duplicate keys).  Here's an updated version with the JSON changed to provide an array: http://play.golang.org/p/Wl6kUaivEm

Comment: I will add that the JSON data provided, is not actually an array of objects. It is a single object, where the `name` and `servers` keys appear twice. This will unmarshal into a single `Serverslice` object, but the second set of keys will overwrite the first.
Perhaps it is prudent to include a valid version of the JSON data in your answer.

Comment: Yep.  I noticed that while looking a bit closer at the data and output of my cleaned up program.  Edited accordingly.